# Add onclick open hyperlink event to an html widget created in R

Tags: javascript, r, hyperlink, plotly, htmlwidgets

I would like to be able to do something like [the answer of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057164/adding-hyperlinks-to-shiny-plots) but without using shiny. I also want to bind onclick events which open a hyperlink associated with the data point.

I am using the `saveWidget` function from `htmlwidgets` and know that I can insert javascript code with the `appendContent` function from the `htmltools`
package.

Here is a small sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)

path.test.results <- "C:\\Users\\img\\"

myData <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y=c(3,2,1))
myLinks <- c("https://www.google.com/", "https://stackoverflow.com/", "https://www.r-project.org/")

ggp <- ggplot(data=myData, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
ply <- plotly_build(ggp)

ply$elementId <- "PlotlyGraph"

#javascript <- HTML('<script>document.getElementById("htmlwidget_container").innerHTML = "test";</script>')
javascript <- HTML(paste(
        paste('<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(',"'", 'PlotlyGraph', "'", ').style.display=',
                "'", 'none', "'", '">Hide Plot</button>', sep=''),
        paste('<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(',"'", 'PlotlyGraph', "'", ').style.display=',
                "'", 'block', "'", '">Show Plot</button>', sep='')
        ,sep=''))

ply <- appendContent(ply, javascript)

saveWidget(widget=ply, file=paste(path.test.results, "test.html", sep=""), selfcontained = FALSE)
dev.off()
```

Now obviously I am asking for help for the correct java script code to save in the 'javascript' variable which I then could integrate with appendContent into the html widget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to

- add the Javascript code via `onStaticRenderComplete` in order to execute it once the plot is rendered
- the Javascript event is a simple modification of the example found [here](https://plot.ly/javascript/click-events/#binding-to-click-events)
- the URL is opened via [`window.open`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

For a general solution with different traces, see: [Open hyperlink on click on an ggplot/plotly chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49711131/open-hyperlink-on-click-on-an-ggplot-plotly-chart/49742200#49742200)

The complete code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)

path.test.results <- "C:\\Users\\img\\"

myData <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y=c(3,2,1), urls=c("https://www.google.com/", "http://stackoverflow.com/", "https://www.r-project.org/"))
myLinks <- c("https://www.google.com/", "http://stackoverflow.com/", "https://www.r-project.org/")

ggp <- ggplot(data=myData, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
ply <- plotly_build(ggp)

ply$elementId <- "PlotlyGraph"

html <- HTML(paste(
  paste('<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(',"'", 'PlotlyGraph', "'", ').style.display=',
        "'", 'none', "'", '">Hide Plot</button>', sep=''),
  paste('<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(',"'", 'PlotlyGraph', "'", ').style.display=',
        "'", 'block', "'", '">Show Plot</button>', sep='')
  ,sep=''))

javascript <- HTML(paste("var myPlot = document.getElementById('PlotlyGraph');
myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){
var urls = ['", paste(myLinks, collapse = "', '"), "'];
window.open(urls[data.points[0].pointNumber],'_blank');
});", sep=''))

ply <- prependContent(ply, html)
ply <- prependContent(ply, onStaticRenderComplete(javascript))

saveWidget(widget=ply, file=paste(path.test.results, "test.html", sep=""), selfcontained = FALSE)
```

Comment: Great! Does exactly what I had in mind. Thank you very much, you helped me out a lot!

Comment: I have now tried to apply the same technique onto a stacked barchart. Everything works if I leave everything out of `aes()` apart from `x=x, y=y` in the `ggplot` call. But when I try to add e.g. `, fill=urls` inside `aes()` it seems to mess up the JavaScript functionality. Then always the same link will open (in my case, the first one which is google), no matter on which bar I click. Do you maybe know whats going on?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't encounter this problem before. Please ask a separate question and I am sure somebody has a solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

A slight correction to Maximilian Peters code which did not quite work for me for a factor(x). I am not a Javascript programmer so cannot really explain it (maybe somebody can ?), and just used the plotly example.

(I added the 2 lines with the comments)

```
javascript <- HTML(paste("var myPlot = 
document.getElementById('PlotlyGraph');
                     myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){
                     var urls = ['", paste(myLinks, collapse = "', '"),'];//added
                     for(var i=0; i < data.points.length; i++){
                     window.open(urls[data.points[i].x],'_blank'); //changed
                     }//added
                     });", sep=''))
```