# Plotly R open URL on click with facetting

Tags: javascript, r, ggplot2, plotly

I have a `ggplot2` plot which I then pass on to plotly and afterwards output to `html` with Rmarkdown.
I am trying to set up a JS function to open the underlying URL when clicking on the points.
My question is very similar to this one ([Add onclick open hyperlink event to an html widget created in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107098/add-onclick-open-hyperlink-event-to-an-html-widget-created-in-r)) but the faceting seems to change the order of the points and neither of the solutions available work.

This post ([Open hyperlink on click on an ggplot/plotly chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49711131/open-hyperlink-on-click-on-an-ggplot-plotly-chart)) seems also relevant and I tried implementing the suggested solution but it was not working.

An example of the data would look like:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)

myData <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3, 4, 6), y=c(3,2,1, 5, 4), type = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b"), urls=c("https://www.google.com/", "http://stackoverflow.com/", "https://www.r-project.org/", "https://www.reddit.com/", "https://www.yahoo.com/"))

ggp <- ggplot(data=myData, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
              geom_point() +
              facet_wrap(type ~ .)
ply <- plotly_build(ggp)

ply$elementId <- "PlotlyGraph"



# javascript <- HTML(paste("var myPlot = document.getElementById('PlotlyGraph');
# myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){
# var urls = ['", paste(myData$urls, collapse = "', '"), "'];
# window.open(urls[data.points[0].pointNumber],'_blank');
# });", sep=''))


javascript <- HTML(paste("var myPlot = document.getElementById('PlotlyGraph');
                     myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){
                     var urls = ", toJSON(split(myData, myData$type)), ";
                     window.open(urls[data.points[0].data.name][data.points[0].pointNumber]['urls'],'_blank')
                     });", sep=''))


ply <- prependContent(ply, onStaticRenderComplete(javascript))

ply
```

I think the problem is that `ggplot` does not put the same order as JS expects the data to be in, but I do not know how to handle this case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option which worked for me was to follow the example in the [plotly book](https://plotly-r.com/supplying-custom-data.html) where you pass the urls via the `customdata` attribute. I also tested in a Rmarkdown file. Only issue I encountered was that in the RStudio Viewer the click event did not work for the first point  (but for all other points) but works fine when opening in the browser:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

myData <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6), y = c(3, 2, 1, 5, 4),
  type = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b"),
  urls = c("https://www.google.com/", "http://stackoverflow.com/", "https://www.r-project.org/", "https://www.reddit.com/", "https://www.yahoo.com/")
)

ggp <- ggplot(data = myData, aes(x = x, y = y, customdata = urls)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(type ~ .)

ply <- ggplotly(ggp)

onRender(
  ply, "
  function(el) {
    el.on('plotly_click', function(d) {
      var url = d.points[0].customdata;
      window.open(url);
    });
  }
")
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much (both for the answer and the book)