# ggplot annotate: Include hyperlink?

Tags: r, ggplot2, hyperlink, annotations, label

Is it possible in `ggplot` to create an annotation layer which contains a hyperlink?

I want use `ggplot` in a `shiny` app rather than export to file.

The following does not work:

```
data <- data.frame(
    a = c(1, 2, 3),
    b = c(5, 2, 3)
  )

  data %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(x = a, y = b)) +
    annotate(geom = "label", x = 2, y = 3, label = "<a href = 'http://google.com'>I am a link</a>")
```

Comment: Is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259826/hyperlinking-text-in-a-ggplot2-visualization/42262407) relevant?

Comment: I saw this as well, but I use the ggplot in a shiny app and do not export it to a file...

Comment: re shiny: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057164/adding-hyperlinks-to-shiny-plots

Comment: Thank you - but this post explicitly refers to the plot.ly library, and to clickable points (a thing which can be achieved for ggplot by means e.g. of the ggiraph package as well). I am specifically referring to clickable text in a ggplot annotate layer.

Comment: using `geom = "text"` then `ggplotly(p)` seems to work ... just not a label